# Dynamic Navigation Bar

Tags: asp.net

How I can Make Navigation bar in my site as
A>E>D>S>H......

I tried more to find an example also I searched more but I couldn't find particular example searched I need any one help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_%28navigation%29

You google breadcrumb keyword with which programming language you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you refering to a page navigation breadcrumb that lists the heirarchy of parent pages based on the current child page?

If so you can use the [ASP:Sitemappath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.aspx) control which reads from a Web.sitemap file within your ASP .Net solution. This is appropriate for most static ASP .Net websites where you are manually keeping the sitemap up to date. If you are using a content management system there is usually a mechanism to generate the sitemap content dynamically.

Comment: I used Dynamic content and I selected products these products must have querstring to return again to it,s page